# Token based authentication for user and separate module

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, oauth, spring-security

I have 2 scenarios where I want to implement the token based authentication:

1. I want to implement token based authentication when a user logs in. i.e.. based on username and password , user should get a token and that token should be used with every request.
2. I have a separate independent module which has ID and secret Key. It has to communicate with server in specific interval. I want to implement token based authentication for this module also.

In both the cases token should have these properties:

1. It should be in payload.
2. It should have a timeout period
3. When token expires server should provide a new token,if the session is not expired else it should logout.

Is OAuth 2.0 right choice? If any other approach is better, Please tell me.
What should I do to solve this problem?
Which is the best place to put token in request -Payload or header? and Why?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 is a good choice for the requirements you mentioned: timeout period and refresh-ability.

Stormpath has an excellent OAuth2.0 implementation that gives you what you are looking for out of the box.

Stormpath has both remote and local OAuth2 Implementations and both are freely available. For the remote case you can rely on our backend using any REST client (http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/token-management/) and any of our SDKs. For the local case you can use our Servlet plugin to run a Web-app with out of the box OAuth2 support. Using the docs link above, you can find documentation for these resources.

Using the Stormpath Spring Boot integration, for instance, you could do something like this:

```
http -v --form POST http://localhost:8080/oauth/token \
> 'Origin:http://localhost:8080' \
> grant_type=password username=micah+demo.jsmith@stormpath.com password=<actual password>
```

(This example uses httpie to interact with a locally running Spring Boot instance). The line I've bolded above conforms to the OAuth2.0 spec for authenticating with usernames and passwords. What you get back is a response like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Length: 325
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 16:02:08 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: account=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiIxNDQyNmQxMy1mNThiLTRhNDEtYmVkZS0wYjM0M2ZjZDFhYzAiLCJpYXQiOjE0Mzg3MDQxMjgsInN1YiI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBpLnN0b3JtcGF0aC5jb20vdjEvYWNjb3VudHMvNW9NNFdJM1A0eEl3cDRXaURiUmo4MCIsImV4cCI6MTQzODk2MzMyOH0.wcXrS5yGtUoewAKqoqL5JhIQ109s1FMNopL_50HR_t4; Expires=Wed, 05-Aug-2015 16:02:08 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly

{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiIxNDQyNmQxMy1mNThiLTRhNDEtYmVkZS0wYjM0M2ZjZDFhYzAiLCJpYXQiOjE0Mzg3MDQxMjgsInN1YiI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBpLnN0b3JtcGF0aC5jb20vdjEvYWNjb3VudHMvNW9NNFdJM1A0eEl3cDRXaURiUmo4MCIsImV4cCI6MTQzODk2MzMyOH0.wcXrS5yGtUoewAKqoqL5JhIQ109s1FMNopL_50HR_t4",
    "expires_in": 259200,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

This provides a bearer token that can be used on subsequent requests as well as an expiration. Plus, it has the advantage of being a JWT - JSON Web Token. The JWT is cryptographically signed to ensure that it hasn't been tampered with and it can be decoded to provide additional meta-information to your client, including user information, access controls and expiration.

You could do something very similar using the `grant_type=authorization_code` for interacting using an id and secret, such as for the independent module you mentioned.

[This article](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-for-java/) goes into more detail on token authentication with Java.

Full disclosure: I am a Stormpath employee and I wrote the article referenced above.